# Got stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: Request "random_string": Invalid object while creating a stripe-payment session in python

Tags: python-3.x, stripe-payments

***This is an App code***

```
@app.route("/stripe_pay")
def stripe_pay():
    session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
        payment_method_types=['card'],
        line_items=[{
            'price_data': 'my_price_id',
            'quantity': 1,
        }],
        mode='subscription',
        success_url=url_for('index', _external=True) + '?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}',
        cancel_url=url_for('add_service', _external=True),
    )
    return {
        'checkout_session_id' : session['id'],
        'checkout_public_key' : app.config['STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY']
        }
```

I have tried to make money transactions in my app and watched this [tutorial][1]. I have checked all my secret_keys and imported everything that the app needs.
A debugger argues `cancel_url=url_for('add_service', _external=True),`.
***This is my a JS code***

````
button.addEventListener('click', event => {
    fetch('/stripe_pay')
    .then((result) => { return result.json(); })
    .then((data) => {
        var stripe = Stripe(data.checkout_public_key);
        stripe.redirectToCheckout({
            sessionId: data.checkout_session_id
        }).then(function (result) {
        });
    })
});```
*Thank you in advance*


  [1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cC9jK3WntR8&t=7s
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a price ID already, you should be using `price` in your `line_items`, not `price_data` which requires some child parameters.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-line_items-price